# Schedules and `max_failures` attribute

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle11gr2

Can't get the `max_failures` idea. From the documentation:

> This attribute specifies the number of times a job can **fail on consecutive scheduled runs** before it is automatically disabled.

So, let's suppose I have a schedule. Its running count is 100. Its failure count is 18. Its max failures is 20.

Current run has finished successfully.

I expect: if I will break it - it will run exactly 20 times on state FAILED after which it will be changed to BROKEN

What I get: it runs 2 times so failure count is 20 and despite the fact it were just 2 consecutive runs the schedule is changed to state BROKEN.

What have I missed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think "consecutive scheduled runs" means exactly that. If it succeeds, the failure count should be reset to 0.

**EDIT**

Guess I was wrong, sorry.

Reading up: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17120/schedadmin004.htm

As per Gary's comment - looks like you need to reset the failure count manually.

Comment: Disagree. There's nothing there that says the failures have to be consecutive (though the wording isn't clear). The "restartable" attribute is more relevant to consecutive failures. You need to disable/enable the job to reset the failure count.